# SQL Server 2008: SELECT FOR UPDATE equivalent

Tags: sql-server-2008, locking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server 2008: SELECT FOR UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950031/sql-server-2008-select-for-update)

I have seen a question on here about this however it was old so I will ask again in case a solution now exists.

My issue is this. I have a database table which I wish to select from but I want to lock the rows that I have selected. The reason for this is that I may have another process running that will also want to select the same rows and I want to prevent this.

Imagine I have two processes doing the same thing. One performs a select and begins to perform its processing of the data. Then a few seconds later the next process comes along and does a select but because the rows aren't locked it also takes the same records and begins to process them. This is of course a bad situation to be in. In Oracle you can use SELECT FOR UPDATE which will take out a lock on the rows to prevent them from being used by the 2nd process. How can this be achieved in SQL Server 2008?

EDIT:

I should add that I can only use standard sql statements. I do not have access to procedures, functions etc. It has to be done via a simple statement. Its a long story and a design consideration that has been taken out of my hands. The solution must be able to be stored in a table, retrieved later and then run via the ADO objects in C# in particular assigned to a command object.

Final Edit:

How can a lock be applied to this statement?

```
SELECT  * FROM (SELECT TOP (20) * FROM  [TMA_NOT_TO_ENTITY_QUEUE]  WHERE [TMA_NOT_TO_ENTITY_QUEUE].[STATE_ID] = 2 ORDER BY TMA_NOT_TO_ENTITY_QUEUE.ID) a
```